# Reorder Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to reorder bootstrap columns with useful links in the row with the empty div and the lorem ipsum text below taking up 12 columns.  Tried using clearfix and various column sizes but nothing is working.
[image: layout of page]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!--Links-->
    <div id="content-left" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
      <h2>Useful Links</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4 Title</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </div>
    <!--Links close-->
    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
    <!--Content-->
    <div id="content-right" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-12 col-md-push-0">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>  
    </div>
    <!--Content close-->
    
    <!--Twitter-->
    <div id="content-left" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
      <h2>Twitter</h2>
    </div> 
    <!--Twitter close-->

  </div><!-- row close -->
</div>
```

Comment: The wireframe image you have posted, is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah the wireframe is what I am going for

Answer (score 1):

1. Two of your blocks (`links` and `twitter`) have the same `id="content-left"`. It's wrong. The `id` must be unique.
2. You can wrap `links` and `content` into one additional block and apply negative margin to the `content`.

NB: This solution works if the height of the `twitter` block is not greater than the height of the `links` block.

Please check the result:

```css
#block-links   { background-color: #9fc; }
#block-content { background-color: #ff9; }
#block-twitter { background-color: #fc9; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #block-content {
    margin-right: -200%;
    width: 300% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Additional block -->
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-4">
      <div class="row">

        <!--Links-->
        <div id="block-links" class="col-xs-12">
          <h2>Useful Links</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1 Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2 Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3 Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4 Title</a></li>
          </ul>   
        </div>
        
        <!--Content-->
        <div id="block-content" class="col-xs-12">
          <h2>Content</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>  
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Twitter-->
    <div id="block-twitter" class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
      <h2>Twitter</h2>
    </div> 

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pull and push is a good way to manage this, but this will only work on the same row because this will give the div `left` and `right` property which does not create a new row. A solution (workaround) what I usually use is creating the twitter div 2 times. Like so:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <!-- Links -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <!-- Twitter -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <!-- Twitter -->
</div>
```